# UICollectionView : Cells do not appear/populate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I need some help with a uicollectionview that I've been trying to implement in Objective-C/xcode:  I am unable to have the cells appear/populate the collectionview (CV).
Currently I am using the interface builder, and a custom class for cells.
The CV is to be a wide strip that is a single row of square image cells, that can be scrolled/swept through horizontally.
My attempts at implementation result in the wide strip but it never populates with cells.
I have explored other stackoverflow threads similar to this issue, where they discuss the subclassing of cell but I was unable to make it work.  Have also tried programmatic implementation and had the same issue.  Would really appreciate any insight as I have been stuck at this point for days.  Below the code I am using, are screenshots of interface builder showing different settings... some I know are useful to include and I apologize if I have shared anything useless.

from **ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic)  NSMutableArray *medCollectionCells;
```

from **ViewController.m**

```
#import "CoolCell.h"

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *medCollection;

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    _medCollectionCells = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1st cell",@"2nd cell",@"3rd cell",@"4th cell",@"5th cell",@"6th cell",@"7th cell",@"8th cell",@"5th cell", nil];

    self.medCollection.delegate = self;

    self.medCollection.dataSource = self;

}

// collection view delegate methods

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [_medCollectionCells count];

}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CoolCell *cell = (CoolCell *)[_medCollection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return cell;

}
```

**CoolCell.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CoolCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *customLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *customImage;

@end
```

**CoolCell.m:**

```
#import "CoolCell.h"

@implementation CoolCell

@end
```

**Screen Shots**

[Storyboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hRAv.png)

[Collection View Settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMASH.png)

[Collection View Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf0Pw.png)

[Cell Settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78laL.png)

[Cell Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWQUF.png)

[Interface Builder Outlets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fHKP.png)

Grateful for any assistance/insight.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties are connected to a `View` object in Interface Builder. Maybe remove that since you are setting those properties in code.